# Preserving format while passing DateTime values to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, c#-2.0

I have a TextBox server control on a Web Form, say, *txtDueDate*. I don't want to use DateTimePicker but want to use TextBox itself. The user enters date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

While passing this value to SQL Server 2005 (Express) stored procedure, I use something like:

```
cmdParameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDueDate.Text));
```

The stored procedure has input parameter to handle this value and is declared as:

```
@DueDate SmallDateTime
```

I want to know the default format SQL Server 2005 uses internally to store this date. On my PC, the Windows XP Regional Settings are set to dd/mm/yyyy format. While viewing records through Management Studio, it is stored correctly. But I am worried about users who will be using this web application. The Windows Regional Settings may differ on their PC.

I want to be sure whoever queries the database, the date is displayed in dd/mm/yyyy format. If someone inserts, 02/01/2004, then it **should not become** a valid reverse date like: 01/02/2004.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime` - it doesn't "have" any (string-oriented) format when stored in SQL Server (it's stored as a 64-bit long). If you pass in a parameter to a stored procedure as a `DateTime` already, you should be just fine! The value will be stored by SQL Server *without* changing any formatting - since it doesn't have any formatting associated with it...

The only point the date is **represented** in a given string format is when you look at it in SQL Server Management Studio, or when you convert it to a string format in e.g. your .NET app.

When you need to somehow pass in a string-representation into SQL Server (e.g. for searching etc.), the one that's the most robust and will work with **any** regional/language setting is the **ISO-8601** date format:  `YYYYMMDD` or alternatively (if you need the time portion) `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` (where the `T` in the middle is a literal, separating the date and time portions)

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` values shouldn't be stored as a text-based format in the database anyway - and it sounds like they're not. You should just treat them *as* `DateTime` values. How those values are formatted on the way out is up to whatever's querying the database, and you can't control that without basically just storing text, which you should *not* do. **Treat the value in its "native" format for as much of the time as possible.** Avoid conversions to and from string formats as far as you can.

I would also avoid just using `Convert.ToDateTime(text)` here - how certain are you that the system default format is the correct one to use here? Can you use a set of controls which give you the actual value instead of relying on what the user happens to type?

Comment: @RPK: You've said you don't *want* to - that's not the same thing. I wasn't suggesting passing the text straight into the database - I was suggesting that it's not a good idea to use a conversion which uses the default culture information.

Answer (score 0):

You choices...

1) IF you're worried about users entering a wrong format (wrong as in DateTime.Parse throws an exception), then you need to validate the input

2) IF you're worried about users entering a wrong format (wrong as in DateTime.Parse throws an exception), then use a date picker.

Comment: I am worried on what user is going to see for a simple query like: SELECT DueDate From <Table Name>.

Comment: The user will most likely see the date formatted according to the user's own regional settings, though this depends on how and where the user is executing the `SELECT` statement.  If the select is happening in your application, then you can specify a display format when you display the text to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to date is done client side, by:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDueDate.Text)
```

By default, this uses the current UI culture, but you can specify a culture with the second parameter:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDueDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

Comment: What improvements are achieved by adding culture? Are the correct bits passed to the stored procedure DateTime parameter?