# Date format issue between ssl & non-ssl site. IIS & asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2016, iis-10

**IIS 10 , Windows Server 2016**

I have a strange issue & am finding it hard to diagnose..

I have a website which is on SSL.

I have the same website codebase which is on same server but on a different port but which is not on ssl.

**Now** : 
1) From Normal Website When I am sending date as 23/06/2017. It is being saved properly in the format which i want.

2) However, From the ssl website, When I am sending date as 23/06/2017, I get this error.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

I need some help as to how do i diagnose this issue. Only difference is the presence of a ssl certificate.

The result of this code is being sent to a stored procedure as a parameter.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23/06/2017", "d/M/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Do both sites point to the same database? If not, are you sure the databases are the same?  Two things could be different - the stored procedures might be different so the parameters are different. Or possibly the locale might be different.  The error is about converting nvarchar to datetime. nvarchar is often an SQL data type. You convert to a string in format 'MM/dd/yyyy', and pass it to the proc. If the locale of the database is expecting 'dd/mm/yyyy' it will choke because 23 is not a valid month.

Comment: In futute pass dates as dates to stored procedures. There is no need to pass them as strings (varchar).

Comment: @GregHNZ yes they both use the same database. locale cannot be different as it is the same db with same credential. Also the same codebase is used. i merely copied the ssl site to a non-ssl port

Comment: @evk agreed. but I am using Parameters.AddWithValue() function. so the conversion should happen by default..

Comment: Why not passing `DateTime` to stored procedure using ISO 8601 date format at first place when dealing with possible different cultures? It is the most robust way and works for any regional format. Probably you should look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957616/preserving-format-while-passing-datetime-values-to-stored-procedure.

Comment: But you are converting it to string first (`ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`), so no default conversion can be performed.

Comment: @evk then how did the non-ssl version worked. I know good practice is to pass dates as datetime datatype. but this should work & already works in a lot of codebases. even in ssms u pass a string as MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Don't pass dates as strings. Pass them as DateTime.  
The .Net [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) [maps directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) to SQL Server's [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). All you have to do is parse the string to a DateTime struct in your .Net code and pass it as a parameter to your query.

Answer (score 0):

This should not actually be called an answer. it is just a patch.
As per comments I have removed the `.ToString` & now my code looks like.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23/06/2017", "d/M/yyyy", null)
```

The same code base pointing to the same database & same stored procedure in the same server making a difference in just ssl. this needs to be searched..